# Fetch Params from Nunit3 in C# test fixture

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am using the params argument provided in the Nunit3 version to pass multiple parameters.

However, I am unable to fetch them with the C# test fixture. I have searched but unable to get a correct result.

Can someone provide me with the pointers on how to fetch those param arguments in c#.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: nunit3-console "D:\Codebase\Automation\ReportGenerationAutomation\bin\Debug\Automation.dll" --test=Automation.Report --params:Code=XXX --params:Date=2011-05-16 --work="D:\Codebase\Automation\ReportGenerationAutomation\bin\Debug"

Comment: This is the command for nunit3. I need to fetch the parameters Date and Code in C#. This command runs successfully, but I am stuck at the retrieving part hence, no C# code is available for that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you are using both NUnit console 3.4.1 and NUnit Framework 3.4.1.

Your command line option of `--params:Code=XXX --params:Date=2011-05-16` looks correct. You can also combine multiple parameters with a semicolon, `--params:Code=XXX;Date=2011-05-16`

To access the parameters in your unit tests, use `TestContext.Parameters.Get("Code")` in your tests. There is also a `string Get(string key, string default)` and a `T Get(string key, T default)` which does a `Convert.ChangeType`.

It isn't well documented yet, so see the [pull request that implemented the feature](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/pull/1570/files) for more information.

Here is an example test,

```
[Test]
public void TestCommandLineParameters()
{
    var code = TestContext.Parameters.Get("Code", "<unknown>");
    var date = TestContext.Parameters.Get("Date", DateTime.MinValue);

    TestContext.WriteLine($"Fetched test parameters {code} and {date}");
}
```

Which I run with the command line and NUnit 3.4.1,

```
nunit3-console.exe --params:Code=XXX --params:Date=2011-05-16 .\nunit-v3.dll
```

In the output, I see

```
=> nunit.v3.TestParamsTest.TestCommandLineParameters
Fetched test parameters XXX and 2011-05-16 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Hey Rob... good answer, but we do have docs for both the command-line part and the TestContext part. If we need something else, like a how-to article, maybe we can get some user to write it for us. I don't have an actual use case that would lead to a good write-up.