# Pass parameters to NUnit via command line

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I'm using command line in order to run my Nunit tests. additionally, I would like to pass a parameter to my [Setup] from the command line as well. 
my current command is:

```js
ECHO
START nunit-console "D:\tfs\QA - Automation\Projects\ReportAppeal\ReportAppeal\bin\Debug\ReportAppeal.dll"
```

where should I add the parameter I would like to pass to my [Setup]? 
BTW, currently I'm using Nunit version 2.6.4

Update:
I have tried to "send parameters" by making [TestCase], but apperantely Selenium does not allow that.

```js
        [SetUp]
        [TestCase("Chrome")]
        [TestCase("IE")]
        public void Setup(string RunnerDriver)
        {
            if (RunnerDriver == "Chrome")
            {
                _webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            else if (RunnerDriver == "IE")
            {
                InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                options.EnableNativeEvents = false;
                _webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
                _webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:/www.foo.com");
            }
        }
```

but I'm getting an error says:

```html
Result Message: Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method: Setup
```

Comment: I don't know if Selenium adds anything that allows you to do this, but it is available in NUnit 3 if you are willing to upgrade. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346286/fetch-params-from-nunit3-in-c-sharp-test-fixture/38350905#38350905

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276278/nunit-test-setup-method-with-argument there are couple of options there

Answer (score 0):

@KirilS.  - the link you shared contains a workaround for my issue.Cheers